# Report Portal: "Start time" dynamic update - how does it work?

Tags: reportportal

I've noticed that time filter "Last 7 Days" doesn't show all necessary results (in my case - the last result, that was received today at 0:29). But filter works as expected when I create custom range from "0:01" 7 days ago till "23:59" today. I wonder, what will happen, if I select option "Dynamic update"? Will it work for me as "Last 7 Days", but with my "0:01" start time?

Answer (score 2):

`Last 7 days` you consider according to your local time.
Server consider it as his local time.
So you can have a difference with couple of hours.

This planned to be fixed.